# Ruby on Rails: Custom getter or custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to display a default avatar image if someone has not added a photo.  I'm assuming I need to either do a custom getter in the model or a helper.

If I did the getter would it look something like this:

```
def avatar_url
  "default_url" unless self.avatar
end
```

Comment: Are you using carrierwave gem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `read_attribute` method to detect the presence.

```
def avatar
  read_attribute("avatar") || default_avatar
end
```

Comment: Question on this, avatar is the actual value in the database, I was going to add an additional property to the model of avatar_url which returned a default if there is one, otherwise return a string value

Comment: That is what this avatar method does. It intercepts the call to the attribute and returns the database value if it's not nil, otherwise it returns `default_avatar`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to set the default at the database level using a migration. That way you don't have to do anything special for the default situation.

The migration might look something like:

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.string :avatar, :default => 'default_url'
end
```

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html